Angular Update Text On Click
I'm trying to build an Angular component wherein the text of a span changes onClick.
I'm using separate files but tried to mash them together so again, the @Component syntax may not be 100% accurate, the only issue I'm facing with the app is the change on click of the first  text.
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgIf, TitleCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { LandmarkMenuComponent } from '../landmark-menu/landmark-menu.component';
import { Location } from '../../../../interfaces/Location';
import { Landmark } from '../../../../interfaces/Landmark';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landmarks',
  standalone: true, 
  imports: [ NgIf, TitleCasePipe, LandmarkMenuComponent, DialogModule ],
  template: '

  @if (!currentLandmark.contents && !emptyLocationSearched){
  
  @if (!emptyLocationSearched){
    <p>{{landmarkSentence}}<span class="location" (click)="searchEmptyLocation()">{{currentLandmark.name}}</span>.</p>
  }
  
  @else if (emptyLocationSearched){
    <p>You search {{currentLandmark.name}} thoroughly, but find nothing</p>
  }
}

@else if(currentLandmark.contents){
  <p>{{landmarkSentence}}<span (click)="changeLandmarkMenuDisplay(true)" 
                                 class="location">{{currentLandmark.name }}</span>!
  </p>
}
  
<app-landmark-menu 
    *ngIf="landmarkWithTarget && landmarkMenuDisplay"
    [landmarkWithTarget]="landmarkWithTarget"
    [(display)]="landmarkMenuDisplay">
</app-landmark-menu>.'
  styleUrl: './landmarks.component.scss'
})

export class LandmarksComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() currentLocation!: Location;
  @Input() currentLandmark!: Landmark;
  @Input() landmarkSentence!: string;

  landmarkWithTarget?: Landmark;
  landmarkMenuDisplay: boolean = false;
  emptyLocationSearched: boolean = false;

  constructor (
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['currentLandmark'] && this.currentLandmark){
      if (this.currentLandmark.contents[0] !== undefined) {
        this.landmarkWithTarget = this.currentLandmark;
      }
      else {
        this.landmarkWithTarget = undefined;
      }
    }
  }

  searchEmptyLocation() {
    this.landmarkSentence = "You search thoroughly but find nothing in";
    this.emptyLocationSearched = true;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  changeLandmarkMenuDisplay(event: boolean) {
    this.landmarkMenuDisplay = event;
  }

}

I've tried multiple things including:

Using *ngIf statements previously before updating to v18 & trying @if.
Using different lifestyle hooks including OnChanges & the below manual change detection.
Updating the landmarkSentence in TS, rather than in the template.

I could put the text in a separate component altogether however this feels like such a simple manipulation that I feel this must be encountered practically daily.
I searched exhaustively for an answer but I can't seem to get it to work.

In response to a comment, this is the pertinent part:
@if (!emptyLocationSearched){
    <p>{{landmarkSentence}}<span class="location" (click)="searchEmptyLocation()">{{currentLandmark.name}}</span>.</p>
  }
  
  @else if (emptyLocationSearched){
    <p>You search {{currentLandmark.name}} thoroughly, but find nothing</p>
  }

On clicking the span, I want the @else if statement to render.

You have made this more complicated than it needs to be by meshing everything up, you only need to use the ngIf directive and show relevant content depending on your boolean, try stripping your code sample to only the relevant parts and will assist

please provide a stackblitz example

Question edited for brevity and clarity.
